# Type inference of foldLeft with a covariant empty seed

Tags: scala, functional-programming, type-inference

Below function extracts 'N' number of elements from a given list. It works as expected. But I am not able to understand why the typing "[List[A]]" needs to be given to the function foldRight while it is invoked. "items" has been already declared with this type and foldRight is invoked on it. So it supposes not to be needed. But without it, syntax error is yielded.

Can you please help why the typing is mandatory.

```
def first[A](items: List[A], count: Int): List[A] = {
  items.foldLeft[List[A]](Nil) { (a: List[A], i: A) =>
     if (a.size >= count) a else i :: a
  }.reverse
}
```

Comment: Leaving out a type annotation in this case should *not* produce a syntax error. Can you please show the actual code that is producing the error, as well as provide the full error message?

Comment: <console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : a.type (with underlying type List[A])
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
            if (a.size >= count) a else i :: a
                                 ^
<console>:13: error: type mismatch;
 found   : List[A]
 required: scala.collection.immutable.Nil.type
            if (a.size >= count) a else i :: a
                                          ^

Comment: That is a type error, which is to be expected. But you should *not* get a syntax error. Please, show the syntax error you are getting and the code that leads to that syntax error.

Comment: Actually it is a type error; not a syntax error. Thanks Jorg for your help!

Answer (score 3):

Because of `Nil`. `Nil` does not carry any useful `type` information to be used in inference. Use `List.empty[A]`  instead `Nil` and you will be able to skip typing. `Nil` is monomorphic, and you need the polymorphic equivalent of it which `List.empty[A]` actually is.

Comment: But that would give a type error, whereas the OP says that they are getting a syntax error.

Comment: When I try to compile code with `Nil` and without `[List[A]]` I get exactly type error. It's a common beginner misconception about `Nil`, `None` and scala type inference. They are monomorphic but they used in a polymorphic context.

Comment: actually,I am getting type error. sorry, I told it was a syntax error.